# How to use update button to change the text of an input field using a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I am doing an assignment to update a text field when an update button is pressed so far. My code looks like this:

```
function updatePhotoInfo(){

var retrieve_images_script = SERVER + "/image.php?username="+USERNAME;
//@ToDo
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
imageData= JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
console.log(imageData.length); 
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", retrieve_images_script, false);
xhttp.send();

var dField = document.getElementsByClassName("dField").innerHTML;
var updateField = document.getElementsByClassName("dField").new.innerHTML;
console.log("dField");

if (dField != updateField) {
dField == updateField;
};
```

Comment: please be more precise. what do you experience as beeing the wrong behaviour. what have you tried yourself so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So generally what I would do is the following. Say we have a button with ID=my-btn

```
document.getElementsByID('my-btn').onclick = function(){
  //If the name of your text filed ID is my-txt
  document.getElementsByID('my-txt').innerHTML = "DONE!"

}
```

This is one way to do it, but if you have the option take a looking into jquery.  It makes this kind of stuff a lot easier to manage.

See this Pen for details [CODE PEN](http://codepen.io/KAPastor/details/grzpZy/)

EDIT:  This one includes a field:
[SAME WITH Field](http://codepen.io/KAPastor/pen/KzRdqm)

Comment: lol it must be done using Javascript, I'm a newbie at this web thing with servers and all, but that is to update the field with what I want it to have in, but I want it to be done like how I am updating this text field. I.E what ever input the user puts in, will replace the old text.